# Disable Mouse Exit Edge Fullscreen when moved to top

Tags: microsoft-edge, fullscreen

I'm using Edge fullscreen and I'd like to disable the "Move mouse cursor to top" disable Edge fullscreen feature. Then the only way would be using the F11 key. I'm finding myself accidentally closing fullscreen all the time. Is there a setting or a regedit I can make?

Comment: Perhaps make Edge almost but not quite full screen so that what is occurring does not happen

Comment: I just tested Chrome and it does work better, it has an "X" that appears when I get to the top of the screen, which is WAY better than Edge at least.